# How do I remove all whitespaces from a string?

Tags: java, string, function, replace, whitespace

I'm trying to remove all whitespaces from a string. I've googled a lot and found only `replaceAll()` method is used to remove whitespace. However, in an assignment I'm doing for an online course, it says to use `replace()` method to remove all whitespaces and to use `\n` for newline character and `\t` for tab characters. I tried it, here's my code:

```java
public static String removeWhitespace(String s) {
    String gtg = s.replace(' ', '');
    gtg = s.replace('\t', '');
    gtg = s.replace('\n', '');
    return gtg;
}
```

After compiling, I get the error message:

```
Error:(12, 37) java: empty character literal
Error:(13, 37) java: empty character literal
Error:(14, 37) java: empty character literal
```

All 3 refer to the above `replace()` code in `public static String removeWhitespace(String s)`.
I'd be grateful if someone pointed out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

There are two flavors of `replace()` - one that takes chars and one that takes Strings. You are using the char type, and that's why you can't specify a "nothing" char.

Use the String verison:

```
gtg = gtg.replace("\t", "");
```

Notice also the bug I corrected there: your code replaces chars from the original string over and over, so only the last replace will be effected.

---

You could just code this instead:

```
public static String removeWhitespace(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("\\s", ""); // use regex
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will use this. Also if I have to use replace() as mentioned in the assignment, will I have to create 2 additional new strings to remove all whitespaces?

Comment: @Shreyash if you must use `replace()`, do this: `return s.replace(" ", "").replace("\t", "").replace("\n", "");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = " Test example    hello string    replace  enjoy   hh ";
        System.out.println("Original String             : "+s);
        s = s.replace(" ", "");
        System.out.println("Final String Without Spaces : "+s);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Original String             :  Test example    hello string    replace  enjoy   hh                                                                         
Final String Without Spaces : Testexamplehellostringreplaceenjoyhh
```

Another way by using char array :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = " Test example    hello string    replace  enjoy   hh ";
        System.out.println("Original String             : "+s);
        String ss = removeWhitespace(s);
        System.out.println("Final String Without Spaces : "+ss);
      
    } 
    
    public static String removeWhitespace(String s) {
        char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
        String gtg = "";
        
        for(int i =0; i<charArray.length; i++){                
            if ((charArray[i] != ' ') && (charArray[i] != '\t') &&(charArray[i] != '\n')) {
                gtg = gtg + charArray[i];
            }
        }    
        return gtg;
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Original String             :  Test example    hello string    replace  enjoy   hh                                                                         
Final String Without Spaces : Testexamplehellostringreplaceenjoyhh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify an *empty character* for the [`replace(char,char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) method, you should do it like this:

```java
public static String removeWhitespace(String s) {
    // decimal format, or hexadecimal format
    return s.replace(' ', (char) 0)
            .replace('\f', (char) 0)
            .replace('\n', (char) 0)
            .replace('\r', '\u0000')
            .replace('\t', '\u0000');
}
```

But an *empty character* is still a *character*, therefore it is better to specify an *empty string* for the [`replace(CharSequence,CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method to remove those characters:

```java
public static String removeWhitespace(String s) {
    return s.replace(" ", "")
            .replace("\f", "")
            .replace("\n", "")
            .replace("\r", "")
            .replace("\t", "");
}
```

To simplify this code, you can specify a *regular expression* for the [`replaceAll(String,String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method to remove *all whitespace characters*:

```java
public static String removeWhitespace(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("\\s", "");
}
```

---

<sup>See also:

• [Replacing special characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65366260/15402945)

• [First unique character in a string using LinkedHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66387637/15402945)</sup>