# How to remove space after the decimal point without removing other spaces?

Tags: java, string, text, replace, textview

I have one `String` that has multiple values in single string. I just want to remove the space after decimal point only without removing other spaces from string.

```java
String testString = "EB:3668. 19KWh DB:22. 29KWh";

testString = testString.trim();
String beforeDecimal = testString.substring(0, testString.indexOf("."));
String afterDecimal = testString.substring(testString.indexOf("."));

afterDecimal = afterDecimal.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

testString = beforeDecimal + afterDecimal;

textView.setText(testString);
```

Here as in my string there is two values in single string
`EB:3668. 19KWh` and `DB:22. 29KWh`.
I just want to remove space after decimal point and make `String` like this:

```
EB:3668.19KWh DB:22.29KWh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `string.replaceAll("\\. ", ".");`

Thanks to Henry for pointing out I had to escape the `.`

Answer (score 3):

You can use 2 capture groups and match the space in between. In the replacement use the 2 groups without the space.

```
(\d+\.)\h+(\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rRH0Vm/1)

```
String testString="EB:3668. 19KWh DB:22. 29KWh";
String afterDecimal = testString.replaceAll("(\\d+\\.)\\h+(\\d+)","$1$2");
System.out.println(afterDecimal);
```

Output

```
EB:3668.19KWh DB:22.29KWh
```

Or a bit more specific pattern could be including the KWh:

```
\b(\d+\.)\h+(\d+KWh)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X9dwui/1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in front of an editor right now, but wouldn't you be able to do this with the replaceAll method in a single line, without breaking it up?

```
var text = testString.replaceAll(". ", ".");
```

Comment: You would be surprised on the effect of this. See also the answer by mindoverflow.

Comment: Ah yeah, good catch. That's why I wanted to test it with an editor :D

Answer (score 0):

You can remove unnecessary spaces between the *decimal point* and the *fractional part* as follows. This code also removes other extra spaces:

```java
String testString = " EB:3668. 19KWh   DB:22. 29KWh ";

String test2 = testString
        // remove leading and trailing spaces
        .trim()
        // replace non-empty sequences of space
        // characters with a single space
        .replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
        // remove spaces between the decimal
        // point and the fractional part
        // regex groups:
        // (\\d\\.) - $1 - digit and point
        // ( )      - $2 - space
        // (\\d)    - $3 - digit
        .replaceAll("(\\d\\.)( )(\\d)", "$1$3");

System.out.println(test2); //EB:3668.19KWh DB:22.29KWh
```

---

<sup>See also: [How do I remove all whitespaces from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66697162/15402945)</sup>